# Can't understand this output

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
def temp(c):
    f = c * 9/5 + 32
    if c <= -273:
        print("not possible")
    else:
        return f
print(temp(-273))
```

It is outputting the correct answer but I can't understand why it's also printing `None` with it whenever the if condition is fulfilled.

Comment: When `c <= -273`, your function prints "not possible", and returns `None`. And your `print(temp(-273))` prints the return value of the function.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we call the inbuilt print function, the function expects a value to print out. In your code when `print(temp(-273))` is called, the if part of condition is executed however there is not a value returned. By default, a function which doesn't explicitly return anything returns `None`. That is what happens after calling the `print()` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
def temp(c):
    f= c* 9/5 + 32
    if c <= -273:
        print(" not possible")
    else:
        return f
```

Is equal to this:

```
def temp(c):
    f= c* 9/5 + 32
    if c <= -273:
        print(" not possible")
    else:
        return f
    return None
```

Because functions in Python always return something, and that something is `None` if there is nothing else returned.

So the two cases of your `if-else` -block are essentially like this:

```
c <= -273:
    print(" not possible")
    print(None)  # the functions return value

c > -273:
    print(c * 9/5 + 32)  # the functions return value
```